# i want to create a dictionary of list of dictionaries

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

i want to create a dictionary of an array of dictionaries from a list of node pairs and their weight.

```
nets = pd.read_table('data/nodes.txt', header = None)
bb = np.array(nets).tolist()
graph = collections.defaultdict(dict)

for row in bb:
    graph[row[0]][row[1]]=row[2]
    graph[row[1]][row[0]] = row[2]

print(dict(graph))
```

which resulted in this dictionary

```
{0: {1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 6, 7: 8}, 1: {0: 2, 2: 5, 4: 7}, 2: {0: 3, 1: 5, 11: 5, `5: 4}, 3: {0: 6, 11: 4, 6: 2}, 4: {1: 7}, 5: {8: 3, 2: 4}, 6: {9: 3, 3: 2}, 7: {0: 8}, 8: {5: 3}, 9: {10: 6, 6: 3}, 10: {9: 6}, 11: {2: 5, 3: 4}}`
```

and want a it in this form.

```
{0: [{1: 2}, {2: 3}, {3: 6}, {7: 8}], 
1: [{0: 2}, {2: 5}, {4: 7}], 
2: [{0: 3}, {1: 5}, {11: 5}, {5: 4}],
3: [{0: 6}, {11: 4}, {6: 2}],
4: [{1: 7}], 
5: [{8: 3}, {2: 4}], 
6: [{9: 3}, {3: 2}], 
7: [{0: 8}, 8: {5: 3}], 
9: [{10: 6}, {6: 3}], 
10: [{9: 6}], 
11: [{2: 5}, {3: 4}]}
```

Comment: The format you say you want would be a lot less useful than what your code currently produces. Why do you think it's a better format?

Comment: @Blckknght its an input sequence to an algorithm

Comment: @StephenRauch, that only wraps the whole set with a square bracket

Comment: `{k1: [{k2: v2} for k2, v2 in v1.items()]
           for k1, v1 in a_dict.items()}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily if you really want to, though I'd look carefully at where you're going to *use* this data structure to see if your existing more logical structure could be made to work instead.

Anyway, here's a quick implementation that should do what you want:

```
graph = collections.defaultdict(list)

for row in bb:
    graph[row[0]].append({row[1]: row[2]})
    graph[row[1]].append({row[0]: row[2]})
```

Comment: i get this error,  graph[row[0]].append({row[1]: row[2]})
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'. What am i  doing wrong? the original array is of this sequence [[0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 3], [0, 3, 6], [0, 7, 8], [1, 4, 7], [1, 2, 5], [2, 5, 4], [2, 11, 5], [3, 6, 2], [3, 11, 4], [5, 8, 3], [6, 9, 3], [9, 10, 6]]

Comment: Sounds like you didn't change the `defaultdict`'s factory. Use `list` if you want inner lists.

Comment: can  you help me with the code that will revert the nested dictionary to its original list